# Restrict access to amazon WorkSpace by IP Address?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a simple question which I don't think has a simple answer.

I would like to use Amazon Workspaces but a requirement would be that I can restrict the IP addresses that can access a or any workspace.

I kind of get the impression this should be possible through rules on the security group on the directory, but I'm not really sure, and I don't know where to start.

I've been unable to find any instructions for this or other examples of people having done this. Surely I'm not the first/only person to want to do this?!

Can anyone offer any pointers??

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Comments given by the @Mayb2Moro; he obtained information from AWS Support that the restriction based on the Security Group or VPC wouldn't be possible as the Workspaces connectivity would go via. another external endpoint [management interface in the backend].

---

<strike>Yes you are right, you need to work on the security group configured while the workspace is setup. The process goes like this,</strike>

1. Pick the security group used while the Workspace bundle was created
2. Go to the EC2 -> Security Group  and select the security group and restrict them to your Office's Exit IP.

[image]

PS : Image Source - http://www.itnews.com.au/Lab/381939,itnews-labs-amazon-workspaces.aspx

Comment: Hi - thanks, I got this far, but couldn't see how to do point 2. Amazon have told me what I want to do is just not possible.

Comment: "Unfortunately it is not possible to lock down Workspaces to only specific IP addresses. When users access Workspaces they aren't connecting through the interface that is connected to the VPC, but through a management interface on the backend. "

Comment: If anyone has actually achieved this, I would love to hear how :)

Comment: Given that you have got the confirmation from AWS Support that the restriction based on IP wouldn't work; you have to fall back on what we do before the availability of the WorkSpaces service - VMware or Terminal Services or Remote Desktop Services etc.

Comment: Just curious what is the use case; with the notion of Workspace kind of environment would be targeted towards anywhere access like desktop / ipad etc.

Comment: Use case for us to is to provide access to a Windows desktop on-premise, but cloud-managed.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can assign IP Access Control Groups to a Directory that is associated to your workspaces.

In the IP Access Control Group, you can specify the IPs that you wish to allow access to the workspaces.

Refer to the [IP Access Control Groups for Your WorkSpaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/amazon-workspaces-ip-access-control-groups.html) for the official documentation.