# How to restrict access to the AWS WorkSpace service to certains IPs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, workspace, windows-firewall

How can I (if is possible) restrict access from just specifics IPs addresses to my WorkSpaces?

I tried using the Security Group associated to the WorkSpace interface, but no results. Seem that the connection from the WorkSpace Client to the Windows OS is routed through an internal interface that AWS don't manage using VPC/SG.

I tried adding IP restriction to the PCoIP Windows Firewall Rules the the WorkSpaces have, but no result. There are the rules:

```
PCoIP - Agent Service
PCoIP - Arbiter Service
PCoIP - Encoder
```

Maybe exist something that reach the WorkSpace that keep the IP address of the PC that are using the WorkSpace Client, and with that we could try to block that connections except from certains IPs in the Windows Firewall. Any idea?

Comment: Based on responses to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28246194/restrict-access-to-amazon-workspace-by-ip-address, it appears your deduction that the connection is routed through another interface is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/workspaces/Best_Practices_for_Deploying_Amazon_WorkSpaces.pdf, this seems possible, but I haven't tried yet.

> **Contractors and consultants:** In the Amazon WorkSpaces
>   Management Console, disable Internet Access and the Local
>   Administrator Setting. Then add a security group under the Security
>   Group settings section to enforce a security group for all new WorkSpaces
>   created under that directory.
>
> For consultants’ WorkSpaces, limit outbound and inbound traffic to the
>   WorkSpaces by applying a default Security group via the AD Connector
>   settings to all WorkSpaces associated with the AD Connector. The security
>   group would prevent outbound access from the WorkSpaces to anything
>   other than HTTP and HTTPS traffic and inbound traffic to RDP from the
>   Helpdesk subnet in the on-premises network.